# Rendering GORM classes from Spring Boot

Tags: groovy, grails-orm, spring-boot

I'm trying to write a simple Spring Boot controller that renders a GORM instance and failing.

Here's a shortened version of my code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value='/test', method=GET)
    User test() {
        return new User(username: 'my test username')
    }
}
```

I get the following error message:

`Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: users.domain.User["errors"]->grails.validation.ValidationErrors["messageCodesResolver"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: users.domain.User["errors"]->grails.validation.ValidationErrors["messageCodesResolver"])`

The error seems to be caused by extra properties injected by GORM. What is the proposed solution for this? Will this eventually be solved in `gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot`? Should I simply disable `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` (I don't have a lot of experience with Jackson so I'm not entirely sure what side effects this may have)? Should I use Jackson's annotations to solve the problem? Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to get rid of the error using this code:

```
@Component
class ObjectMapperConfiguration implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper

    @Override
    void afterPropertiesSet() {
        def validationErrorsModule = new SimpleModule()
        validationErrorsModule.addSerializer(ValidationErrors, new ErrorsSerializer())
        objectMapper.registerModule(validationErrorsModule)
    }

}

class ErrorsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ValidationErrors> {
    @Override
    void serialize(ValidationErrors errors, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) {
        jgen.writeStartObject()
        jgen.writeEndObject()
    }
}
```

Obviously this solution is far from perfect as it simply nukes all validation errors but right now it is good enough for me. I am pretty sure the Spring Boot team will have to address this issue eventually as the GORM objects are also being serialized with some internal Hibernate properties like `attached`. I'm not accepting this answer as it is not an acceptable solution for most scenarios, it basically just squelches the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me. 
So I used this instead and the error disappeared.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(["errors"])
```

Comment: I am using Spring Boot + Groovy for this application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using springBootVersion '1.4.1.RELEASE' with gorm & hibernate5:

```
compile("org.grails:gorm-hibernate5-spring-boot:6.0.3.RELEASE")
```

I am having to include the following at the top of each domain class in order to use them in a client response (i.e. json serialization using jackson):

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(["errors", "metaClass", "dirty", "attached", "dirtyPropertyNames"])
```

When using springBootVersion '1.3.5.RELEASE' I was able to get away with:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(["errors"])
```

This is trending in the wrong direction :)